# Renormalization vs RG

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

What is a good example of something that is doable via old fashioned renormalization (e.g. using counterterms) that is less achievable using renormalization group methods à la Wilson?

Comment: I've hard some claim that it may be better to use the former for calculational reasons. I suppose the refined question would be - are there cases where it is more convenient to use the former than the latter?

Comment: For a reference on that claim, "Lectures on Phase Transitions and Critical Phenomena" by Goldenfeld states in Ch. 12 that accurate calculation of critical exponents beyond $O(\epsilon)$ in an $\epsilon$-expansion is more streamlined using renormalization than a momentum-shell Wilsonian calculation.

Comment: The momentum shell "Wilsonian" approach becomes tough beyond one-loop. Often at one-loop you can just take the shell you're integrating out to be small and then the integral can be approximated by its integrand evaluated at the shell, but at higher loops dealing with the nontrivial phase space is way messier.